# Convert ID2D1Device1 to ID3D11Device

Tags: nvidia, direct3d, direct2d, reflex

I want to implement NVIDIA Reflex to My Direct2D application. I have a ID2D11Device, but NvAPI_D3D_SetSleepMode requires Direct3DDevice.

I know that Direct2D is based on Direct3D. So, I think that I can acquire Direct3D Device from Direct2D Device. But, I can't find any solution.

How to get Direct3D device from Direct2D device? If I misunderstand conceptions, please let me make know a right concepts. Thanks.

Comment: ID2D11Device doesn't exist at all. If you mean ID2D1Device then in general you already have a Direct3D/DXGI device and create a D2D device over it somehow. How do you create your D2D1Device in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the `ID2D1Device`, you had to start with a Direct3D device. Use that one.

```
// Obtain the underlying DXGI device of the Direct3D11.1 device.
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice)
        );

    // Obtain the Direct2D device for 2-D rendering.
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_d2dFactory->CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), &m_d2dDevice)
        );

    // And get its corresponding device context object.
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
            D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
            &m_d2dContext
            )
        );
```